# How to send and receive notification

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, signalr

I just want to send and receive SignalR notification from Window Service to all connected clients.
I am using asp.net web forms not MVC.

Comment: Are you using a Windows service or ASP.NET? You have tagged and mentioned both, and the answer is completely dependent on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see find an article on codeproject that discusses [sending group notification to clients using Signalr](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/404662/SignalR-Group-Notifications). As far as i know asp.net and asp.net mvc should both be ok here

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure whether it's possible to call clients directly from Windows Service but as workaround you can call some special aspx page from service with needed arguments and this page can send notification like as usual.